# How to shift all the items in an array to the right(by 1) using method map?

Tags: javascript

i have no idea on how to solve this problem. How can i shift all the items in an array by one, using the map method?

```
function shift(arr) {
  // code
}
const b = [{ value: "" }, 8, "left"];
console.log(shif(b));
```

The output should be ["left", { value: "" }, 8];

Thank you very much to everyone!

Comment: `b.unshift(b.pop());`, I'm not sure, if `map` method can even be used to achieve this.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant `map` technically "can" but horrible idea to do it that way.

Comment: Notice that the method above shifts the array in-place. If you need to keep the original array, you've to deep clone it first. The shifting can be done when cloning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subtract one from the index and add the lenght to prevent negative values, get the reaminder with the length and take it as index for the element for mapping.

```js
function shift(arr) {
    return arr.map((_, i, a) => a[(i + a.length - 1) % a.length]);
}

const b = [{ value: "" }, 8, "left"];

console.log(shift(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` may not be the most appropriate here, but if you insist,

```js
let arr = [{value: ""}, 8, "left"];
let shifted = arr.map((_, i, a) => a[(i + 1) % a.length]);
console.log(shifted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could shift/rotate to right **from 0 places to above** without using any Array built in functions.

If the places are greater than the array size reduce it to number of places within the array size.

As for the main part you need to worry about the transition from the last index to the starting one `if(i + places > list.length - 1)`otherwise just put the element onto the new position defined by the place argument.

```js
const list = [4, 3, 2, 10, 12, 1, 5, 6];

function rightShift(list, places) {
  const result = [];
  if (places > list.length) {
    places = places % list.length;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i + places > list.length - 1) {
      result[places - (list.length - i)] = list[i];
    } else {
      result[i + places] = list[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//Shift right 1 place
console.log(rightShift([{ value: "" }, 8, "left"], 1));

//Shift right 154 places
console.log(rightShift([4, 3, 2, 10, 12, 1, 5, 6], 154));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I came here Running the same Problem and i ended up doing this**

this also was my answer to  **CyclicRotation** on Codility
Rotate an array to the right by a given number of steps.
it scores **100%**

```js
function arrayShift(arr, shiftCount) {
  let result = [];
  if (arr.length == 1 || shiftCount == 0) {
    return result;
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    result[(index+shiftCount)%arr.length] = arr[index];
  }
  return {result}
}
console.log(arrayShift([1,2,3,4,5],3))
```